# Mocha and ts-node gives 'Unsupported Args'

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, ts-node

In my `package.json` I have defined my test script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ts-node/register ./test/**/*.ts",
    "build": "npx tsc"
}
```

When I run `npm test` I get back the result:

```
> mocha --require ts-node/register ./test/**/*.ts

error:   Unsupported Args: --require ts-node/register ./test/**/*.ts
```

It seems to somehow be the command interaction. Even if I run it manually `node .\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha --require ts-node/register "./test/**/*.ts"` it fails with the same message. If I remove `--require ts-node/register` it runs, but fails when running the test on `import` statements because my test files are Typescript files.

How do I make mocha work with ts-node?

Comment: This command should work, everything is fine with it. This means that something else is wrong (the wrong version of mocha maybe?), and we're not seeing the whole picture.

Comment: I'm using mocha 9.1.3 and ts-node 10.4.0. I am using CommonJS module type. There are no configurations or other settings related at all to those two modules than my script call. Suspect it might be a bug with Windows command args handling.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. Just tried on a Linux machine and it gives the same response.

Comment: There's [a section in ts-node's readme](http://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#mocha), dedicated specifically to mocha. It doesn't directly answer the question, but may be useful. Have you had a look into it?

Comment: Yes, I looked both at ts-node and mocha for how to use them together. Even copying the exact same line you linked `mocha --require ts-node/register --extensions ts,tsx --watch --watch-files src 'tests/**/*.{ts,tsx}'`, it correctly gives: `Error: No test files found: "tests/**/*.{ts,tsx}"` but when I change from `tests` to `test` to get a valid path I get back the same error `Unsupported Args ......`.

Comment: So I managed to circumvent the problem by moving the info into package.json:
`"mocha": {
    "extension": ["ts"],
    "spec": "test/**/*.ts",
    "require": "ts-node/register"
  }`.

Still not sure, whether to then close it, since the original problem still remains when used in the command line.

Comment: Would you mind posting your findings as an answer then?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find an answer to how to solve it with the command line, but I circumvented the problem by moving the options into package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
},
"mocha": {
    "extension": ["ts"],
    "spec": "test/**/*.ts",
    "require": "ts-node/register"
}
```

Update: I found the error. I was moving some code without test to having test. The logger was defined in a main.ts file which had some code that ran that was not behind any guard. In fact the error `Unsupported Args` was my own error message.

The act of referencing a winston logger caused the code in main.ts to run. For some reason this error does not happen now that the mocha options are in package.json even though the logger is still referenced which I find confusing. I am not sure why whether the options are directly in the command line, or they are in the package.json causes such a behavior difference. Regardless, the lesson learned is never reference into your main "running" module.

Answer (score 0):

My `package.json` file has it in `scripts`

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -r ts-node/register tests/test.ts"
    },
```

And after this I can run `npm test` and everything seems good.

Versions in `devDependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai-http": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/expect": "^24.3.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.18",
    "@types/node": "14.14.30",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
}
```

Comment: I tried rebuilding a fresh project and copying part by part my code over. Your work fine, until I copy some code that, could - but never does - call a winston logger.